# Execute update on linkedserver table with a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, linked-server

I'm trying to execute an update on a table that is on a linked server, with informations from a table on my current server and the query was taking something arround 2 hours to update a single test row, here is my query

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, 'SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 FROM 
SPV.DBO.TESTTABLE')
SET FIELD1 = LT.FIELD1, 
    FIELD2 = LT.FIELD2, 
    FIELD3 = LT.FIELD3, 
    FIELD4 = LT.FIELD4
FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, 'SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 FROM 
SPV.DBO.TESTTABLE') L
INNER JOIN LOCALTESTTABLE LT ON LT.FIELD1 = L.FIELD1 COLLATE 
Latin1_General_CI_AS    
AND LT.FIELD2 = L.FIELD2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
UPDATE L
    SET FIELD1 = LT.FIELD1, 
        FIELD2 = LT.FIELD2, 
        FIELD3 = LT.FIELD3, 
        FIELD4 = LT.FIELD4
FROM LINKEDSERVER.SPV.DBO.TESTTABLE INNER JOIN
     LOCALTESTTABLE LT
     ON LT.FIELD1 = L.FIELD1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AND
        LT.FIELD2 = L.FIELD2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

Four-part naming is simpler than `OPENQUERY()`.

Your version might also work, but you need to use the alias for the `update`:

```
UPDATE L
    SET FIELD1 = LT.FIELD1, 
        FIELD2 = LT.FIELD2, 
        FIELD3 = LT.FIELD3, 
        FIELD4 = LT.FIELD4
FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, 'SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 FROM 
SPV.DBO.TESTTABLE') L INNER JOIN
     LOCALTESTTABLE LT
     ON LT.FIELD1 = L.FIELD1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AND
        LT.FIELD2 = L.FIELD2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  ;
```

Otherwise, you are updating all the rows in the table.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I forgot to say on the original post the reason why I'm trying to do it with the openquery is because the original code currently is performing with the four-part naming, but is taking to long to complete so I was asked to do this change to increase performance.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was the missing alias!